# Proof using function continuity

Tags: calculus

Given that f(x) is continuous at 0 find a if:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 5 - a$$
And

$$f(0) = a +3$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is lim as x goes to 0, not to a. Overall it is ok!

Comment: Thank you! :D Should I answer it? or can I just mark it as closed?

Answer (score 1):

Use 
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$$
So that:
$$ a + 3 = 5 - a$$
$$ a = 1 $$

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question. Do please fix  the question, and put the answer here.

Comment: Did you mean like this?